# Turn off message when running system

Tags: php, system, unzip

I'm using `system('unzip -o source.zip');` to unzip via php, but when I run it. It always display message Archive:..... every files inside zip package.

I want it keep silent while working. How can I do that. Thanks for help!

Comment: Is this some kind of deploy script?

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like this

```
system('unzip -o source.zip >/dev/null 2>&1');
```

Or maybe better, use `shell_exec('unzip -o source.zip');`

Side note: Make sure to use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) before passing anything to shell.

Comment: The solution has worked for me. Thanks @vfsoraki

$targetFile = '/www/audra/fineName';
system('unzip -P 123 '.$targetFile.' -d location >/dev/null 2>&1');

Answer (score 0):

Using `system` if not really a good way.

There's how you can do it without this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('source.zip') === true) {
    $zip->extractTo('/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'Done';
} else {
    echo 'Error opening the zip file';
}
```

Comment: Some server doesn't support  ZipArchive(). And I read some document, I need put -q in command of system() function. It don't display any message. Thank for help!